# Check if byte is a value from enum

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, enums

This is my enum:

```
internal enum ServiceCode
{
    AAA = 0x54, BBB = 0x24, CCC = 0x45
};
```

In my method, I want to check, if the byte number is in my enum:

```
Byte tByteItem;

// tByteItem converted to decimal for example: 0x54 -> 84

// now I want to check, if 84 (=0x54) is in my enum
// it should be true, because AAA = 0x54 = 84
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceCode), tByteItem))
{
    // ...          
}
```

My if clause doesn't work, how can I do that?

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: My if-clause doesn't work, what is the right if-clause

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a great way to describe a problem. 'This code throws an `ArgumentException` saying "Enum underlying type and the object must be same type or object must be a String. Type passed in was 'System.Byte'; the enum underlying type was 'System.Int32'."' would be something *useful* to put in your question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I was just getting ready to ask as I was digging through the source of `Enum.IsDefined`. Good call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>I'm guessing that</strike> The reason that `Enum.IsDefined` isn't working is because you're it performs a type check to ensure that the value that you're passing matches the base type of the `Enum`. In this case, since you didn't specify, the base type is `int`.

You're passing it a `byte` rather than an `int`, which means that the type check fails and throws an Exception. You could try simply casting your `byte` to an `int` when calling the method which should take care of the issue:

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceCode), (int)tByteItem))
{
    //..
}
```

You could also try changing the underlying type of the `Enum` to byte, which would limit the available values for later:

```
internal enum ServiceCode : byte
{
    AAA = 0x54,
    BBB = 0x24,
    CCC = 0x45
}
```

Or, if that still doesn't work, you could try an alternate method. Something like:

```
// Get all possible values and see if they contain the byte value.
if(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceCode).Contains(tByteItem))
{
    //...
}
```

Which is obviously less than ideal, but could get you through in a pinch.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't specify your enum, the base type of an Enum is an integer. By deriving it from `byte`, this might work:

```
internal enum ServiceCode : byte {
    AAA = 0x54,
    BBB = 0x24,
    CCC = 0x45
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceCode), (byte) 0x54);//true
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceCode), (byte) 0x84);//false
```

(tested on the `csharp` interactive shell of mono)

---

Note this has some side effects: it is for instance impossible to assign a value `0x1234` to an `enum` member (since a boolean can only reach values between `0x00` and `0xff`).

---

This is because C# does not really "use" the notion of an Enum. Internally the enums are stored by their binary value, and if necessary (e.g. `ToString()` method) special methods are used. In that sense enums in C# are less object-oriented than their java counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ServiceCode`s are just meant to represent values that can be converted to `Byte` values, you might want to consider changing the base type of the enum:

```
internal enum ServiceCode : Byte
{
    AAA = 0x54, BBB = 0x24, CCC = 0x45
};
```

Alternatively, you'll should go with [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186292/15498)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceCode))) {
    if(tByteItem == value) {
```

However, you might want to consider a Dictionary.  That is the data structure most commonly used for your application.

Comment: If Justin nailed it, your answer isn't adding much other than a "best practice" that isn't backed up with reasoning.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it runs in O(n) with n the number of elements of the enum. There are faster methods (e.g. binary search or a bit string) to check membership.

Comment: True enough, which a dictionary would accomplish.  Its also always nice to rely on well-tested and documented code from the library publisher rather than trying to roll-your-own.